# Direct Access on Sever 2012R2 - SSL Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate, direct-access

I have a question in regards to certificates when implementing Direct Access on a Server with 2 NICs.  One directly connected to internet and the other internally configured.  I have *.domain.com wildcard cert on my main DC and I'm wondering how to properly request, export or import the SSL certificate needed to securely connect outside the network.  Do I request SSL through MMC Certificate Template snap-in? Request SSL through IIS 8? Import *.domain.com onto Direct Access Server and attach that certificate to website?

Thank you

Comment: Will you be supporting Windows 7 clients?  If so you are going to need an internal CA anyway.  In that case, just request a cert from your CA, and don't try to move that wildcard.

Comment: windows 10 enterprise clients